# Can capacitive coupling from waving hands affect op-amps 4 feet away? What is the magnitude?

Tags: operational-amplifier

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/JaT8jT_vL24

In the video above I was standing about 3.5 feet away from the electrodes of the EEG unit. Whenever I waved my hands, there were large amplitude distortions in the EEG display (zoomed in but still 3.5 feet away). Before and after the waveforms were more uniform and have flatter amplitudes as you can obviously see. Note all electric sources near it (like electrical wires) were disabled. .

Can electric flux from the human body or hands travel 3.5 feet away to affect the electrode wires serving as antenna (and the op-amps)? What is the magnitude of this electric flux that can do it? Is this called capacitive coupling? I thought this only occurred for high current sources.

Comment: absolutely. This is how a Theremin works.

Comment: It has nothing to do with high currents.

Comment: I wore slippers during the tests so my feet was not in contact with the floor.. so which part is the ground? my hands? please illustrate because I still don't get it exactly, thanks.

Comment: Due to the slippers you might have acquired tens of thousands of volts of static electricity on your body and this is easily detected at a few feet.

Comment: Could your environment be on the dry side? Has your apparel been freshly laundered, perhaps coming from a dryer? These conditions exacerbate static as @Andyaka suggests.

Comment: is capacitor coupling the same as static discharge forming a complete circuit via air?

Comment: my apparel are always machine washed and air dried. my floor is wooden, when i stepped on it bare, it doesnt ground the static. how do i remove the static in my body so i can test again? tnx